# Point out errors in a JavaScript Loop

Tags: javascript, function, loops

What's wrong with this function? I want to add 1 to c_count until it reaches 100

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var result = cMat(0); function cMat (c_count) { var limit = 100; match = 1; while (c_count != limit) c_count ++ match; if (c_count == 95) { c_count = 10; } } return (c_count) } </script>
```

Comment: So what is the issue with that code?

Comment: looks like you're trying to return `c_count` from outside the `cMat` function, rather than returning `resuilt`

Comment: `c_count ++ match` - use `c_count++;` or `++c_count;` or `c_count += match` or ... instead. Call `result = cMat(0);` after your function definition. Also add an `{` after your `while` or remove a `}` at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to add 1 to c_count until it reaches 100

You're resetting `c_count` to 10 every time it reaches the value of 95, so it's never reaching your limit. Your match variable doesn't seem to be used, so it can be removed. One thing to check is where the value of c_count is in relation to 100. If it's greater than 100, you need to decrement the value instead of incrementing it.

```
 var result = cMat(0); 

 function cMat (c_count) { 
   var limit = 100;
   while (c_count != limit) 
      if(c_count < limit) {
         c_count++;
      } else { // Implied that it's greater than the limit at this point
         c_count--;
      }
   } 
   return c_count;
 }
```